# No libraries found by Visual Studio/Visual Micro

Tags: visual-studio-2015, arduino

I am trying to get Visual Micro working with Visual Studio 2015 and Arduino 1.6

Right now, whenever I tried to build an Arduino project that uses a library (any library), I get the following error:

```
Compiling debug version of 'sketch_aug09a' for 'Intel® Galileo Gen2'
sketch_aug09a.ino:6:20: fatal error: ACE128.h: No such file or directory
:compilation terminated
Error compiling project sources
```

It builds just fine if there are no libraries involved.

It doesn't matter if the library is a standard Arduino library, or a third-party one like the example I just pasted. I know it is not the project file, because the exact same .ino files will build and load onto my boards just fine when I use the standard Arduino IDE.

I did make sure that hidden files were visible, and it does see the libraries in the following structures.

```
Sketch_aug09a>src>_micro-api-readonly>libraries
>Wire>src>Wire.h
>ACE128-master>ACE128.h
```

I am still pretty new to Visual Micro, does anyone have any idea what is going on?

Comment: It's possible the ACE128 lib was not marked to be compatible with Intel. We recently updated to allow libraries even if they have an invalid architectures= in the library.properties. There was a simple remedy at the time. This is a late posted comment, hopefully, at the time, you asked this question in the visual micro forum at https://www.visualmicro.com/forums and got an answer. Sorry that we can't  monitor all the Arduino questions on this site.

Comment: If I'm being brutally honest, I did not find the answer to this question and gave up. I can't even remember what this project was for off the top of my head. That said, I appreciate you getting back to me.

Comment: For anyone else reading this please use the forum at visualmicro.com because we do not have the resource to monitor stackoverflow. Thanks for the response @MechanicalMan

Answer (score 0):

It seems visual micro has not detected your arduino library paths.

- Check `Visual Micro -> Add Library` in Visual Studio. You should be
  able to see and include libraries from there.
- Otherwise got to
  `Visual Micro -> ide -> <Configuration Manager>`. Check whether your
  paths are correct.
- If no success, `Help > Cleanup Old Versions` from
  Visual Studio menu .
- If no luck try latest version of Visual Micro. It shows `vMicro` in menu.

[image: Cleanup old versions]